# How to fix the position of a div while using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am trying to fix the position of a `div` whose ID is `#acc3` (which has more `div`s inside it) by using this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="accordion" id="acc3">
    <div class="accordion-group" id="acc3g">
        <div class="accordion-heading" id="acc3h">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#acc3" href="#div3">
                Inventory Graph</a>
        </div>
        <div id="div3" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner" id="acc3i">
                <div id="inventoryLevels"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
        position:fixed;
       }
```

**JS**

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#acc3').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#acc3').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

The problem is that the div is not able to maintain its width, which should be equal to `col-md-9` when you scroll. I have searched a lot on the internet about the issue and seems that the hack is to calculate the width of `#acc3` on page load and impose it on it and its children. Another problem occurs here when you resize the window: For that I tried listening to the `resize()` module and the code for it looks something like this:

**JS**

```
var chartWidth = $('#acc3').width();
$('#acc3').css('width', chartWidth + 'px');
$('#acc3g').css('width', (chartWidth-2) + 'px');
$('#acc3h').css('width', 'inherit');
$('#div3').css('width', 'inherit');
$('#acc3i').css('width', 'inherit');
$('#inventoryLevels').css('width', (chartWidth-32) + 'px');

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowToChartWidthRatio = windowWidth/chartWidth;

$( window ).resize(function() {
    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    var newChartWidth = newWindowWidth/windowToChartWidthRatio;
    $('#acc3').css('width', newChartWidth  + 'px');
    $('#acc3g').css('width', (newChartWidth-2) + 'px');
    $('#acc3h').css('width', 'inherit');
    $('#div3').css('width', 'inherit');
    $('#acc3i').css('width', 'inherit');
    $('#inventoryLevels').css('width', (newChartWidth-32) + 'px');
});
```

This still works fine (though I think it is very hacky). Now as I am using HighCharts to make the graph, the width of its various elements needs to be changed as well. Like this, I am stuck in a deeper problem.
Could anyone tell me how I can simply fix my nested `div` `#acc3` without any of this rigmarole? Or if I am going the right way, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: So, your initial problem is that `#acc3` does not maintain it's width when class `.fixed` is added on scroll?

Comment: suggest you create a simple demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is true.

Comment: Alright, can you setup a Bootply with your code? I've got some ideas but i'll have to test them.

Comment: @Tim I may not be able to do that as it is blocked in the office I work in.Also, `.affix()` gives the same issue.

Comment: @charlietfl I am sorry, that website is blocked in the office I work in.

Comment: doubtful you will get much help without a demo that can be inspected in browser developer tools